# css relative position keep inside container

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code centers an element, but if the content is taller than the container a portion of the top of the element will be left above the top of the container. Is there a method of forcing the element to stay within the container? Though I'm sure it's possible with javascript, it would probably be pretty ugly. I would rather a css option. Just point me in the right direction.

EDIT:

I do not want to "hide" the overflow, I want the opposite. Visit the jsfiddle resize the preview panel smaller than the element and you will see what I mean

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oj307azv/3/)

html

```
<div class="fill">
    <div class="myClass">
        hello world!
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.fill {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.myClass {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in an `inline-block` container with `max-height: 100%` and `max-width: 100%` then apply positioning to the container. Apply sizing and styling to the element inside the container

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oj307azv/15/))

HTML

```
<div class="fill">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="myClass">
            hello world!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.myClass {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
position: fixed;
```

for both container and myclass.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oj307azv/11/)

Comment: overflow: scroll will let you see things in a scroll. Otherwise I assume the text size has to be shrunk.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out if you want your text to be vertically centered. Your line height was to big that's why it's hiding the rest of the contents.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.myClass {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.myClass {
    width: 300px;
    line-height:200px;
    background: rgb(50,150,250);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border-radius: 2px;
  
    display: -ms-flexbox!important;
    display: -webkit-flex!important;
    display: flex!important;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: normal;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
      max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fill">
    <div class="myClass">
      hello world!
      Long text here!
      Blah Blah blah!
      Chewie!
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure what you want, check out my edit. You put `  max-height: 100%;` on the `.myClass` element so it wouldn't go beyond the parent container.

Comment: then if you want to be able to scroll down then put `  overflow: auto;` on your class element